# Использование нескольких бд в одном запросе в Python

Tags: python-3.x, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

Я работаю через python с базами данных. У меня есть sql-запрос который внутри себя использует таблицы из разных баз. Как мне воспроизвести это с помощью python?

В обычном случае в работе с одной бд я создаю engine через sqlalchemy.create_engine. Затем с помощью pandas.read_sql создаю датафрейм.
А здесь нужно использовать две базы, которые находятся на одном сервере, что осложняет задачу. Переподключаться не могу, так как использую временные таблицы в запросе.

Comment: А в чём проблема, если доступ к базам идёт внутри SQL запроса, питон вроде не при чём тут?

Comment: @CrazyElf , питон говорит Adaptive Server connection failed. Потому и не понимаю. При коннекте к серверу я не указываю бд. Типа, просто подключись ко всему серверу. Или нужно явно указать? Если да, то как? Через запятые или квадратные скобки - неверно

Comment: врядли вам здесь смогут помочь не видя кода запросов и той части кода где идет соединение с БД... И приведите пожалуйста в теле вопроса SQL запрос, в котором вы обращаетесь к таблицам из разных БД